# Apache Redirect certain HTTPS requests to HTTP not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi I have been working on this for a while and just know I am doing something stupid but just can not see it.  What I want to do is to redirect certain pages so they are always shown using HTTPS and all other pages if they are requested through HTTPS they are redirected as HTTP.

I have done lots of searching around the issue and found accepted answers on Stackoverflow that just did not work for me.  So here Is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !(finance/enquiryForm)(.*)
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !(offerentry)(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://dev.staging.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(finance/enquiryForm|offerentry)(.*) https://dev.staging.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What is currently happening is that the pages that I want to redirect from https to http work fine but the pages I want to show as HTTPS get a redirect loop and fail.  If I comment out the top section the HTTPS pages I do want redirect fine.  So how do I get the redirect loop to stop?

**EDIT**
The full .htaccess file with the codeigniter etc stuff.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
</Files>

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !/(finance/enquiryForm|offerentry) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} /(finance/enquiryForm|offerentry) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]


# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(fuel/install/.+|fuel/crons/.+|fuel/data_backup/.+|fuel/codeigniter/.+|fuel/modules/.+|fuel/application/.+|\.$

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !fuel/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules based on `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(finance/enquiryForm|offerentry) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(finance/enquiryForm|offerentry) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Test them in Chrome dev tool and see what redirects are you getting.

Comment: Well it certainly does something different.  Using this I get all pages working fine but only in http.  The pages I want to be https go back to http.

Comment: I am using Codeigniter  But the problem only occurs when I add the .htaccess rules. If I use some simple rewriterules for each of the pages to force them to https it works fine. It is doing the oppostite. Forcing all pages  other than those in my question to go to http when requested via https that is not working,  The redirects are firing before it gets to the framework code.

Comment: Added to original question above

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !(finance/enquiryForm|offerentry)
RewriteRule (.*) http://dev.staging.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (finance/enquiryForm|offerentry) https://dev.staging.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I gave this a try and still get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when going to the HTTPS pages

Comment: And now, try without the `^` in the last RewriteRule. I don't know what your real link is... and if that can be a problem or not...

Comment: I am afraid still no joy.  I don't understand why this does not work. It is almost like it is ignoring the ! in the second RewriteCond. If I put in specific pages in the RewriteCond rather than a negation it works fine.

Comment: I don't understand neither... Try with R=302, and other browser. That can be a problem with a cache...